# Internet Explorer not loading js scripts in .new framework 4.7.2 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, internet-explorer, model-view-controller

I've created and deployed an asp.net framework 4.7.2 mvc application.
It works well with all other browsers but when it's opened with IE the scripts do not run.
This must be a compatibility issue, how can I resolve this?

Note: the scripts are both jquery and javascript integrated together.

Comment: Please consider showing us some of the code that is not working. Are you using arrow functions?

Comment: yes i am using arrow functions, ive been doing some research and ive found that ie doesnt support them, is that correct ?

Comment: Yes that is correct